# Variable call in Ruby on Rails tutorial listing 6.23

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

The question is in regard to the [Rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org). In particular I have a doubt about [listing 6.23](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users#code-email_downcase), this line:

```
before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
```

I am curious about the variable "email" - where does it come from? Is it some kind of short Ruby syntax to call the left-hand side variable? Or does it call to the model's attribute (it would make passing the block variable redundant though)?

I'd appreciate anyone ridding me of my confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can omit passing the user to the block

```
before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
```

I personally prefer not using blocks and write named methods for this

```
before_save :reformat_email


private
def reformat_email
  self.email = email.downcase
end
```

Comment: I see, so basically in the tutorial the author accessed the same place in memory in two different ways, am I correct? And I can replace it with either `self`, as you mentioned, or with `{ |user| user.email = user.email.downcase }`, and both would do the same thing?

Comment: @STT: yes, exactly. I think it's just a small typo. There's no reason to access the same email in two different ways (other than to confuse the reader :) )

Answer (score 1):

**This is only valid if `user` in the example is the same as `self` AND regarding the example with using before_save in an ActiveRecord::Base class**

`email` is short for `user.email`, but when assigning a value you can't use `email =`, you must do `user.email =` otherwise you will only assign to a local variable.

The example is changing what's in `user.email` to `user.email.downcase`

And I think that when you use a `before_save` with an argument it will be `self` in that argument

Comment: Incorrect. There's no way `email.downcase` is interpreted as `user.email.downcase`.

Comment: ? please explain, in the example in the question I think `email` will be the same as `user.email` because Rails are making a method for all attributes, or?

Comment: They *might* point to the same value, but `email` is **not** a shortcut for `user.email`. It's interpreted as `self.email` because there's no local var with this name. See the difference?

Comment: I'm still not convinced, as I added in my suggestion, when you use a before_save with an argument it will be self in that argument?

Comment: it will likely be. **BUT** if you take this out of context of activerecord, your statement completely breaks. Because `email` is `self.email`, not `user.email`. Be careful with statements like this.

Comment: I'm assuming that before_save with that syntax is used in an ActiveRecord class

Comment: It could also be used anywhere else. It's just a method with a block.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20083/discussion-between-244an-and-sergio-tulentsev)